# Creating refs outside of component. Is that a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a library which requires exporting a couple of functions for users to call upon. Those functions need access to component ref in order to add/remove classNames and auto scroll etc.

I was able to get it to work by moving my ref (created by `React.createRef`) outside of the component itself (NOT talking about defining it outside of the `constructor` but inside the component)

Here's how my code looks like (used a class component instead of functional as the hook `useRef` obviously can't be used outside)

```js
import React, { PureComponent, createRef } from "react";
    import { typingEffect } from "../redux/actions/dispatch";
    import { containerRef } from "./Container";
    
    let typingRef = createRef();
    
    export async function displayTypingEffect() {
      await typingEffect();
      typingRef.current.className += " rcb-is-typing";
      containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight + 700;
    }
    
    export function hideTypingEffect() {
      typingRef.current.className = "rcb-typing-container";
      containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight + 700;
    }
    
    export default class Typing extends PureComponent {
      render() {
       return (
        <div ref={typingRef}>
          rest of the component code which is unnecessary for this question
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I am just wondering if there's a possibility of any unforeseen issues or bugs if I follow this pattern.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This makes the `typingRef`

1. a global variable (inside the module), and
2. be created outside of any React life cycles

`typingRef` will be the same object for every instance of the `Typing` component, i.e. if two components are created from the `Typing` class, both will write to the same `typingRef`. Your API will provide access some DOM element, but you can not be sure which one it currently is.

`typingRef` is created as soon as the file is imported, before React even starts, and will live for the life time of the Javascript code, not the life time of any React component.

I think (not 100% sure) any DOM elements referenced by `typingRef` will be kept (at least) until `typingRef` gets overwritten (or the Javascript execution is ended). So if a Typing component gets unmounted, the DOM element (and everything that's connected to it) is still kept in memory. So your API will provide access to "useless" DOM elements.

Comment: thank you for sharing these points. These certainly make sense. Is there anyway I could achieve my use case and NOT cause the issues listed above? Reading the documentation on React, both forwardRef and useImperativeHandle allow me to use those functions within react components but not outside.

Comment: There would be different approaches. I suggest not to use methods, but properties, e.g. `<Typing displayTypingEffect={ true } />` (declarative instead of imperative). Alternatively you might export react custom hooks instead of plain functions.

Comment: That would have helped if I was exporting 'Typing' component to the end user :) It's part of my library. Will have to look for alternatives or restructure my lib. Thank you for your time.